# Get site collection in timer job

Tags: sharepoint-server, timer-jobs, custom-timer-job

I use this code to get the site collection :

```
SPWebApplication webApplication = this.Parent as SPWebApplication;
SPContentDatabase contentDb = webApplication.ContentDatabases[targetInstanceId];
SPSite Site = contentDb.Sites["sites/AA"];
SPWeb Web = rootSite.OpenWeb("BB");
```

the fact is `Site == null` because `contentDb.Site` contains only one site collection(the root site)

How can I get the siteCollection named: `sites/AA`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the timerjob properties collection and retrieve it in the Execute method of timerjob

follow below url contains solution:
http://adicodes.com/timer-job-in-sharepoint-for-specific-site/

Code in the feature activated event store the siteUrl

```
string key = "mySiteUrl";
string value = web.Url;

TimerJob tmrJob = new TimerJob(webApp);
//remove the key if already exists
bool isKeyExists = tmrJob.Properties.ContainsKey(key);
if (isKeyExists)
{
    tmrJob.Properties.Remove(key);
}
tmrJob.Properties.Add(key, value);
```

Get the url in the Execute method

```
public override void Execute(Guid targetInstanceId)
{
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.Properties["mySiteUrl"].ToString()))
    {
        mySiteUrl = this.Properties["mySiteUrl"].ToString();
    }

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(mySiteUrl))
    {
        using (SPSite mySite = new SPSite(mySiteUrl))
        {
            using (mySiteWeb = mySite.OpenWeb())
            {
                //provide your logic here for the site
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: should ,the key = "mySiteUrl"; , is my site collection name/ hardcoded name?